# Prove that $mn=1$ if and only if either $m=n=1$ or $m=n=-1$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-explanation

Prove that $mn=1$ if and only if either $m=n=1$ or $m=n=-1 $

I am struggling with the general concept of proofs. 
From the above statement I understand that I need to prove two statements:

> 1. If $mn=1$ then $m=n=1$ or $m=n=-1$ and
> 2. If $m=n=1$ or $m=n=-1$ then $mn=1$

I believe I have proved the second statement with the following:
 $mn=(1)(1)=1 $ 
or
$mn=(-1)(-1)=1$ by substitution/assumption. Do I need to reference any axioms or is this substitution allowed?

I am struggling with how to prove the first statement. Can I rearrange for $m=1/n$ and substitute or is this not allowed in proofs?

Comment: Whenever you have if and only if, it is like you prove both ways. Suppose if you are asked to prove A iff B, you first assume A and prove B and then assume B and prove A. But you have to make a point about what m and n are, if m and n are rational numbers, mn can be 1 without the both given conditions. For example m = 5/3 and n = 3/5. You have to mention the nature of m and n in the statement that is to be proved.

Comment: I still don't understand how to approach proving the first statement. In my question I proved the second statement and realize I need to prove the first I just don't know how to approach the first proof. I understand I need to start with assuming MN=1 but I am stuck with how to proceed.

Comment: Where do $n,m$ live? I imagine it is a ring, but which one?